# Permutations and Counting problem?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Postal codes in Canada have six characters with alternating letters
>   and digits in the form L#L#L#. How many postal codes do not have one
>   letter repeated three times?

What I did is $26*10*25*10*24*10=15600000$, which is apparently wrong. The solution in the marking scheme is like this:

Total number of codes: $ 26*10*26*10*26*10=17576000$

Number of codes with the same letter 3 times is: $26*10*10*10=26000$

Number of codes without the repeated letters is: $17576000-26000=1755000$

What is wrong with my logic? And I don't get the method the marking scheme used.

Comment: Your computation also does not allow a letter to be repeated even twice.

Comment: The $26\cdot25\cdot24$ part of your calculation requires all three letters to be different: as Gregory said, you’re counting the plates with no repeated letters at all. If you want to approach the problem that way, you have to add in the plates that have a pair of identical letters and one that’s different. There are $26$ ways to choose the pair, $25$ ways to choose the odd letter, and $3$ ways to choose which of the three letter positions gets the odd letter, so you should add $26\cdot25\cdot3\cdot10^3$ to your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation also does not allow a letter to be repeated even twice.

Comment: It's so obvious now, thank you!